# Custom font android device by application

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application. I don't want to use a font in an application and just change type of a text view or something. I want to add some fonts on my android device and change my device font. what's the way to add fonts on non-rooted devices? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use other sites, like https://android.stackexchange.com, for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I want to develop an android application. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

> what's the way to add fonts on non-rooted devices?

That is not supported. Apps cannot modify system files in general.